# Different exit status for different Windows

Tags: windows, vb6, exit-code

I'm trying to debug a crash in my application and have noticed something weird.

I have created a simple Visual Basic 6 project with only two buttons. One to crash the application and one to hang the application. The code follows:

```
Private Declare Sub RaiseException Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwExceptionCode As Long, ByVal dwExceptionFlags As Long, ByVal nNumberOfArguments As Long, lpArguments As Long)

Const EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION = &HC0000005

Private Sub cmdRaiseException_Click()
    RaiseException EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION, 0, 0, 0
End Sub

Private Sub cmdLoopForever_Click()
    Do
    Loop While True
End Sub
```

Testing this in Windows XP and 7 yields different exit status:

- Access violation in Windows 7 has exit status 0
- Access violation in Windows XP has exit status -1073741819
- Hanged application in Windows 7 has exit status -805306369
- Hanged application in Windows XP has exit status 1073807364

Do you confirm my findings ? Is there any documentation for this? Exit status code is useless if it is not consistent.

Comment: You are greatly confusing any code that processes this exception.  &HC0000005 always has arguments.  Anything can happen next.  It is also drastically misleading to anybody that sees the exception code, the program did not actually crash from an AVE.  Just don't do this.

Comment: @HansPassant I also tested by using a custom C++ dll to throw a real exception. the result was the same.